# Using Order By in Oracle 11g but the list is not orderred

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have an OrderId column and the values are a mix of single digits like 1,2,3 to 4 digits like 3456.
When I query the table and use Order By OrderId the list is not ordered by OrderId the way I want.

So Instead of showing: 1,8,10,20,70,111,2345,4567

it is showing : 1,111,20,2345,4567,70,8 etc

Is there a way to order this Ids properly? my simple query is like this:

```
select * from a table
order by Orderid
```

Comment: The root cause of your problem ist that you are apparently storing numbers in a `varchar` column. Don't do that. **Always** use the proper data type for the values you want to store. Store numbers in `number` columns and  dates in `date` (or `timestamp`) columns.

Answer (score 2):

This is doing lexicographic sort, that means the column type is varchar2

you need to convert the varchar2 to number and do order by

```
select * from Table
order by TO_NUMBER(Orderid)
```

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, converting to a number doesn't work, there is another trick.  You can sort first by the length and then by the value:

```
order by length(OrderId), OrderId
```